# Wordpress get_posts always returning null, for any post type, with post_status=all, etc

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Been tearing my hair out here, can't get any posts to return in a simple query:

```
get_posts();

get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'meetings',
    'post_status' => 'any'
]);

$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'        => 'meetings',
    'post_status'      => 'any',
    'ping_status'      => 'any',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_parent'      => null
]);
```

When I make a new post type of 'meetings', I can confirm it is created with this status:

```
{
   "ID":100,
   "post_author":"1",
   "post_date":"2020-08-12 16:26:45",
   "post_date_gmt":"2020-08-12 16:26:45",
   "post_content":"",
   "post_title":"Test",
   "post_excerpt":"",
   "post_status":"publish",
   "comment_status":"closed",
   "ping_status":"closed",
   "post_password":"",
   "post_name":"test-2",
   "to_ping":"",
   "pinged":"",
   "post_modified":"2020-08-12 16:43:43",
   "post_modified_gmt":"2020-08-12 16:43:43",
   "post_content_filtered":"",
   "post_parent":0,
   "guid":"http:\\/\\/esh.localhost\\/?post_type=meetings&#038;p=100",
   "menu_order":0,
   "post_type":"meetings",
   "post_mime_type":"",
   "comment_count":"0",
   "filter":"raw"
}
```

Here is the code to register this custom post_type:

```
register_post_type( 'meetings', [
    'show_ui' => true,
    'labels'  => array(
        'name' => 'Meetings',
        'singular_name' => 'Meeting',
        'add_new' => 'New Meeting',
        'all_items' => 'All Meetings',
        'add_new_item' => 'New Meeting',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Meeting',
        'new_item' => 'New Meeting',
        'view_item' => 'View Meeting',
        'search_items' => 'Search Meetings',
        'not_found' =>  'No meetings found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Meetings found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Meeting:',
        // 'parent' => 'eSupport',
        // 'menu_name' => 'eSupport'
    ),
    'show_in_graphql' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'graphql_single_name' => 'meeting',
    'graphql_plural_name' => 'meetings',
    'show_in_menu' => 'esh-sections'
]);
```

So with those post details, can anyone see why get_posts might return an empty set all the time? Even for regular posts ('post_type' => 'all'), it's still empty.

If it helps, here is the exact code and output:

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'        => 'meetings',
    'post_status'      => 'any',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1
]);

dlog("Post type exists?", post_type_exists( 'meetings' ) );
dlog("posts", json_encode($posts));
```

Output:

```
[Wed Aug 12 13:09:49.732013 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 4371] [client ::1:60535] \nPost type exists?, referer: http://localhost:3000/dashboard
[Wed Aug 12 13:09:49.732072 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 4371] [client ::1:60535] \n1, referer: http://localhost:3000/dashboard
[Wed Aug 12 13:09:49.732105 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 4371] [client ::1:60535] \nposts, referer: http://localhost:3000/dashboard
[Wed Aug 12 13:09:49.732119 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 4371] [client ::1:60535] \n[], referer: http://localhost:3000/dashboard
```

Comment: try with post_status `any`

Comment: @jrswgtr Thanks, but no dice.

Comment: see my answer. Did you add `posts_per_page => -1`? I just tested my answer and I confirm it works.

Comment: I did, no idea why it isn't working, sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `post_status => any`

```php
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'meetings',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
]);

var_dump($posts);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no dice. I updated the original post with the code I'm running and the output.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'meetings';` and see if you get any results

Comment: If I run that from mysql terminal, I get a bunch of posts... and see their statuses, bunch in 'auto-draft', others in 'publish' and others in 'trash'. If I change post_status => 'publish', still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, my apologies, I had a an action that was filtering the return:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ESH\Meetings::get_meetings_by_owner' );
```

Disabling those lets me see the posts. Sorry for the confusion!